# Algebraically, how to calculate coefficients for multiple regression with 3 input variables?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I need to run a multiple regression in some limited software that cannot preform any matrix calculations. I am not so good at deriving these on my own and would love some assistance.

I need something similar to these 2 walkthroughs but for a model containing 3 input variables.

https://www.statology.org/multiple-linear-regression-by-hand/

https://www.statology.org/linear-regression-by-hand/

Ex: for simple linear regression b0 = [(ΣY)(ΣX2) – (ΣX)(ΣXY)]  /  [n(ΣX2) – (ΣX)2]
Something like this but for all coefficients for a model with 3 input variables and an intercept.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: You definitely don't want formulas: you want *algorithms.*  There are many of them.  Among the simplest are the sequential ones, such as given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71257/919 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/166718/919.

Answer (score 1):

While you can definitely devise a formula, as whuber asserted in the comment [above](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/625426/algebraically-how-to-calculate-coefficients-for-multiple-regression-with-3-inpu#comment1165860_625426), an efficient algorithm rather than running a formula as a code would be preferable. Nevertheless, if you want to proceed in that vein, check on this Stat.SE [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/589753/362671).

Any such algorithm would be thematically based on [Frisch–Waugh–Lovell theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisch%E2%80%93Waugh%E2%80%93Lovell_theorem). ESL advocates the algorithm of *regression by successive orthogonalization*, which has been explained in this Stat.SE [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/618200/362671). Depending on your programming language, you can write the code based on this algorithm.